# What's the correct sql query for this purpose?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have read in some articles about query's like this:

```
select *
from `log` as a
where not exists  ...
```

but unfortunately I'm complicated: I know what I want but I can't find the correct query for it.

The `all_services` table is the Mother table and each user can  use 7 services in it.  At the beginning, I want to show all 7 services for each user but after that user selected some services and registered those id's in `user_services`  table, I want to show just remaining services like this pic:
[image] 
please give me the compelete PDO code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdlrl.jpg

Comment: whould you please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if found it :

```
$data_obj_se = $db -> prepare("select * from `services`  WHERE id  NOT IN ( select service_id from  `user_services` WHERE user_id='2' )    ");
$data_obj_se -> execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
select a.* from all_services a
join user_services b on a.id = b.service_id
where b.user_id = {user id}
```